# How to add custom p values within brackets in ggplot between discrete y axis points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have a df such as this:

```
plot2=structure(list(partition = c("2", "2b", "2c"), partition_name = structure(1:3, levels = c("Cardiac_significant_enh partition PRS Original OR", 
"Cardiac_significant_enh partition PRS OR × enh_ES", "Cardiac_significant_enh partition PRS OR × enh_TS_tpm"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Num_SNP = c(3157, 3157, 3157
), CoD_per_SNP = c(62.1186923796969, 61.1820673263678, 60.9483894486912
), R2 = c(0.0196108711842703, 0.0193151786549343, 0.0192414065489518
), LCL = c(0.010974448167152, 0.0135183879280951, 0.0112302824404708
), UCL = c(0.0282472942013886, 0.0251119693817734, 0.0272525306574328
), R2type = c("Lee", "Lee", "Lee"), xlabel = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), levels = c("Cardiac significant enh\npartition PRS OR × enh ES (SNP\nN=3157)", 
"Cardiac significant enh\npartition PRS OR × enh TS tpm\n(SNP N=3157)", 
"Cardiac significant enh\npartition PRS Original OR (SNP\nN=3157)"
), class = "factor")), row.names = 4:6, class = "data.frame")
```

And I plots is as this:

```
ggplot(data = plot2,
         aes(
           y=reorder(plot2$xlabel, desc(partition)), 
           x=plot2$R2*100, xmin = plot2$LCL*100, xmax=plot2$UCL*100, 
           colour=plot2$R2type,group=plot2$R2type
           # label=round(R2*100,2)
         )) +  
  geom_pointrange(
    position=pos, size=1, lwd=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=MetBrewer::met.brewer("Johnson", 2),
                     expression(paste(R^2)))+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
    aes(
      y=reorder(xlabel, desc(partition)), 
      x=R2*100,
      colour=R2type,group=R2type,
      label=round(R2*100,2)
    ),
    position = pos, size = rel(4),  show.legend = F,min.segment.length = 0,
    point.padding = NA, box.padding = 0.5)+ #nudge_y = -0.2, 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .15))) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = .7)) + #.6 is default - add a little spacing to the sides
  xlab("") +  ylab(paste0("HCM diagnosis ~"))+theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",  
    text=element_text(lineheight = 0.8, angle = 0, size = 21, color = "gray8")
  )
```

which gives:
[image: Blockquote]

Now, I'd like to add p value brackets as those provided by the [ggpubr geom_bracket() function](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggpubr-how-to-add-p-values-generated-elsewhere-to-a-ggplot/), but this only allows to "compare" discrete x categories, and I have my categorical variables in y.
This is what I'd like to obtain:
[image]

The p values are manually assigned, and I'd like to be able to choose which pairwise comparisons to include or not (e.g., 1st vs 3rd line only).

Comment: You could put your discrete variable on the x axis, your continuous variable on the y axis, then `coord_flip`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Allan, I came up with

```
ggplot(data = plot2,
       aes(
         x=reorder(xlabel, desc(partition)), 
         y=R2*100, #xmin = plot2$LCL*100, xmax=plot2$UCL*100, 
         colour=R2type,group=R2type
         # label=round(R2*100,2)
       )) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size=3.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LCL*100,
                    ymax = UCL*100),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
                width = 0.05, linewidth=1) +
  ## first comparison: original OR ENH partition vs OR * ES
  geom_bracket(data = plot2,
               xmin = reorder(plot2$xlabel, desc(plot2$partition))[[1]],
               xmax = reorder(plot2$xlabel, desc(plot2$partition))[[2]],
               y.position = max(plot2$UCL*100)*1.1,
               label =paste0("MD=",comparisons[6,2],", p=",comparisons[6,5]),
               # tip.length = c(0.02, 0.02),
               coord.flip = TRUE,
               # vjust = -1
  ) +
  ## second comparison: original OR ENH partition vs OR * tpm
  geom_bracket(data = plot2,
               xmin = reorder(plot2$xlabel, desc(plot2$partition))[[1]],
               xmax = reorder(plot2$xlabel, desc(plot2$partition))[[3]],
               y.position = max(plot2$UCL*100)*1.2,
               label = paste0("MD=",comparisons[7,2],", p=",comparisons[7,5]),
               # tip.length = c(0.02, 0.02),
               coord.flip = TRUE,
               # vjust = -1
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=MetBrewer::met.brewer("Johnson", 2),
                     expression(paste(R^2)))+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
    aes(
      x=reorder(xlabel, desc(partition)), 
      y=R2*100,
      colour=R2type,group=R2type,
      label=round(R2*100,2)
    ),
    position = pos, size = rel(4),  show.legend = F,min.segment.length = 0,
    point.padding = NA, box.padding = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .15)))  +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = .7)) + #.6 is default - add a little spacing to the sides
  ylab("") +  xlab(paste0("HCM diagnosis ~"))+theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",  
    text=element_text(lineheight = 0.8, angle = 0, size = 21, color = "gray8")
  )+
  coord_flip()
```

geom_pointrange does not seem to work in this context.